# XSP Configure fails due to mono module dependancy

Tags: linux, mono, rhel, xsp

I have mono installed in my RHEL 5 machine which is visible as follows:

**which mono**

/usr/local/bin/mono

**mono -V**

Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.2 (tarball Wed Oct 16 10:33:49 CDT 2013)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)

When i try to run the configure script for xsp, it fails since it could not find mono.

**./configure**

checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for MONO_MODULE... configure: error: Package requirements (mono >= 2.10.0) were not met:

No package 'mono' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables MONO_MODULE_CFLAGS
and MONO_MODULE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

I tried to resolve this by adding the mono.pc file path to PKG_CONFIG_PATH. 
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

But the issue didn't get resolved and i got the same error nonetheless.

Please help me in finding a resolution for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try following this guide: [Setting up a Build Environment](http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments#Setting_up_a_Build_Environment) (with `MONO_PREFIX=/usr/local` and forget about the gnome parts).

Comment: Thank you! This got me past the OP's error, through to a successful make, but make install failed with System.DllNotFoundException: libc.dylib (on OS X - I've recently build mono 3.8 from github). This I fixed by googling to "add /usr/lib to DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Check the correct location of pkgconfig in your mono installation.I was running with the same error until i found that it was under

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.4.0/lib/pkgconfig/

Comment: Thank you! For others, to set the path run `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.4.0/lib/pkgconfig/`