# Why is no package 'mono' found?

Tags: mono, dependency-management, centos7, banshee

Attempting to install Banshee from [source](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/banshee/2.6/banshee-2.6.2.tar.xz) on a CentOS 7 machine (migrating from Ubuntu and I want to retain my playlists and settings).

**./configure** results in:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (mono >= 2.4.3) were not met:

No package 'mono' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables MONO_MODULE_CFLAGS
and MONO_MODULE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

**which mono**

```
/bin/mono
```

**echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH**

```
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

but if I check for pkgconfig,

**which pkgconfig**

/usr/bin/which: no pkgconfig in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)

**yum provides pkgconfig**

```
1:pkgconfig-0.27.1-4.el7.i686 : A tool for determining compilation options
Repo        : base
```

**yum install pkgconfig**

```
Package 1:pkgconfig-0.27.1-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

A similar question was asked last year with no accepted answer.  One of the answers [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19420480/721073) to a now [non-existent page](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/parallel-mono-environments/) with a purported solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `pkg-config` itself is working all right, configure is not complaining about that. What's missing is the entry for `mono` in the pkg-config database. Make sure you have `mono.pc` in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, or add wherever you have this file to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` as instructed. On some linux distributions, development packages need to be separately installed, such as `libmono-cil-dev` on debian.